# how to parse component implementation for some methods on controller

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two methods that create data in the bank, one creates apartment, the other creates the resident and uses the data of the apartment in the creation of the resident.

I am using the convert implementation of spring mvc to change from id to string when setting the apartment to the dweller.

But when I create the apartment, if the implementation of the converter is in my class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. I can not create the apartment, because the same can not save the id as a string in the database.

How do I disable the implementation of the convert and use it only for when calling the method of creating the dweller.

This is my converter class

```
@Component 
public class AddApartConverter implements Converter<Object, Apartamento> {

    @Autowired(required = false) 
    ApartamentoService apartamentoService; 

    public Apartamento convert(Object element) { 
        if (element == null) { return null; } 
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String) element); 
        Apartamento apartamento = apartamentoService.findById(id);
        return apartamento; 
    } 
}
```

This is the error

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleTypeMismatch
>
> WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento] to required type [br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento] to type [@javax.validation.Valid br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento] for value 'Apartamento [id=null, bloco=1, apartamento=101]'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento cannot be cast to java.lang.String

This is what i need to do

If I put in my class that implements the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
Public void addFormatters (FormatterRegistry registry) {
Registry.addConverter (addApartConverter);
}
```

Apartment:

The method of creating apartments does not work and appears the conversion error mentioned.

If I comment on this code the method of creation of apartment works.

Living:

I can only register a resident if there is an apartment in the database.

If I make an insert in the database for the creation of the apartment.

And register the resident by selecting the apartment that comes from a List of the database, the register works because it converts the apartment id to string.

So that for the apartment register to work, it can not convert the apartment id to string

What I need is that the convert is not called by the method of creating the apartment. That he be called only in the creation of the dweller

Comment: Can you show us your code and error?

Comment: This is my converter class

@Component
public class AddApartConverter implements Converter<Object, Apartamento> {

 @Autowired(required = false)
 ApartamentoService apartamentoService;

 public Apartamento convert(Object element) {
  if (element == null) {
   return null;
  }
  Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String) element);
  Apartamento apartamento = apartamentoService.findById(id);
  return apartamento;
 }
}

Comment: WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento] to required type [br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento] to type [@javax.validation.Valid br.com.grandvalley.pub.model.Apartamento] for value 'Apartamento [id=null, bloco=1, apartamento=101]'; nested

Comment: No one can read in comments without formatting, put the in your post and format it, properly, please.

Comment: Steve, if i insert the values from apartamento directly on database, and get this values on morador view, to create the morador,  the converter works fine.

the issue is only because the converter cannot running on apartamento.

Comment: May you please put the detail you have into the post? People won't waste time digging in comments. BTW, there should be enough details.